# Do Drupal websites have bad performance or are heavy?

Tags: 7, performance

I'm facing a lot of problems with my shared hosting company regarding the performance of my website.

My website is not complicated at all, just text pages, and also some pages using the Views module, I'm not using Panels, and I aggregate my css and js, and also I have 7 image styles (thumbnail,large etc...).

But even so my hosting company told me that I exceeded the memory limit and I have to optimize the website.

I have also another site in a different hosting company .... another problem appears in the database and this is the error message:

> **PDOException: SQLSTATE[00000] [1129] Host '...' is blocked because of many connection errors;**

I don't know if the problem is because of Drupal or something else.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/724/why-is-drupal-7-so-slow might help

Comment: Also, did your host specify what their memory limit actually is?

Comment: Memory limit exactly 786432 KB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's your hosts memory limit?

For MySQL Run this MySQL command

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size'
```

If it's at the [default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) I would see if you can increase it to at least the same size as your database. If you can not, I would look at converting some of your tables to MyISAM.
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/03/choosing-innodb_buffer_pool_size/

Comment: Memory limit exactly 786432 KB and this is the result of sql query 8388608

Comment: 96MB should be enough ram for most things... I would swap in http://drupal.org/project/imagemagick

I would see if you can increase that value in MySQL. If you can not up this value, change all tables except for semaphore, node_access, sessions, queue, batch, and history to MyISAM.

Comment: it does not make a problem to the site